# How do I use Rehype React?

Tags: reactjs, rehypejs

I am trying to convert some html to react components with `rehype-react`, I'm first just testing what I can do but changing a `p` tag to my own custom component that will turn it red however it doesn't seem to be working despite my following of the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rehype-react).

Below is the code I'm trying to run based off the documentation but the console log doesn't output the updated `p` tag. I have tried to find any examples I can online using this package but there doesn't seem to be any that I can find.

Is it a dead package? What I am doing wrong?

```
unified()
      .use(rehypeParse, {fragment: true})
      .use(rehypeReact, {createElement, components: {
        p: MyParagraph
      }, passNode: true})
      .process(text)
      .then((file) => {
        console.log(file.toString())
      })
```

```
function MyParagraph() {
  return (
    <p className='text-red-700'>
      It's working
    </p>
  )
}
```

**Versions**

```
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"rehype-parse": "8.0.4",
"rehype-react": "7.1.2",
"unified": "10.1.2"
```